# Connection closing when downloading a large file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying download a large files (1.5-3GB) in Flutter application with DIO.
All is well in debug version, but in release I get connection breaks at random time: 
DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data, uri = https://unitedrp.ru/files/10475-GTA-SanAndreas-v1-06-cache.zip

In flutter_downloader plugin I have the same error.
HttpClient causes application crash without explanation

```dart
await GetIt.I.get<Dio>().download(
    link, 
    path,
    onReceiveProgress: (receive,total) => onProgress(((receive/total)*100).toInt()));
```

Comment: try to set timeout